# Network service vs AspNet (Asp.Net Machine Account)

Tags: asp.net, iis, permissions

I've a small asp.net application which write logs on the file system in a directory 'Logs'.

I've given the modify permission to Asp.Net machine account for this folder which works fine. However when I tried to deployed it to the another server it doesn't work. I have to give the same modify permission to Network service account also. Why?

Comment: you should check what is new server application pool user and to give correct permissions to it

Comment: Both are Windows 2003 Server R2. But one server not showing the Application Pool node in IIS.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because that's the account that's used to run the application pools under. So on IIS6 and 7 this will be the case. On workstations with IIS5, you won't have application pools, and so the ASP.NET worker process runs under the local `ASPNET` account.

Also, it's better to grant the permissions on the `IIS_WPG` local group, of which the Network Service is a member.

Comment: I've IIS 6 on both servers. So in this case does this make difference?

Comment: In that case, you should only be needing ACL's on the IIS_WPG group. Unless someone's fiddled with the identity of one of the AppPools to make it run under ASPNET...

Comment: I've found a little difference but doesn't know if that is helpful in this case. One server have the IIS 5.0 Isolation checked but another not.

Comment: IIS 5 Isolation mode doesn't use Application Pools, so that explains the difference you're seeing. You shouldn't run IIS 5 Isolation mode *unless* you run ASP.NET 1.0 apps.

Answer (score 0):

Because on your local machine IIS worker process runs under Asp.Net machine account but on a windows server IIS worker process runs under Network service account.

Comment: Thanks for your comment.
Both are Windows 2003 Server R2. So In this case the process must run under Network Service Account only. Why do we have this difference then?